# Registration case studies/research

Tags: registration, signup-signon, best-practice, use-cases, case-studies

I am working on a commercial website where customers choose a template and then use a drag and drop interface to create their own adverts or promos.

Before the customer can access this section though, they need to answer three questions in order to determine price, which is represented in a three price card format, that the customer selects.

There are two trains of thought of this process:

• Either to have sign up/registration at the front of this journey (pre seeing the templates)

• Or at the end of the journey (viewing, filtering, selecting, designing the advert/promo)

Does anyone know of any case studies / research into the registration process for the pros, cons, benefits or risks in either process?

- Context. The business wants to have sign-up/registration up-front as they are concerned customers will come to the site, see the designs and rip them off.

The sign up/registration process asks for name, email, password. An email is sent on confirmation, there aren’t any follow up emails unless the customer explicitly requests it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know studies, but as a potential customer, I'd _strongly prefer_ to see some idea of what your service would provide ("the designs") before creating an account; I'd **definitely** want to see what's on offer before handing over something like credit-card details. If you're worried about people stealing your design collateral, maybe consider some animations/movies of the design process so people can at least get a feel for what they are signing-up for.

Answer (score 1):

Customers hate signing up for an account when all they want to do is buy a product from your e-commerce store. One of the reasons people hate registration so much is because they think it will sign them up for a newsletter too.

Here's the link : https://baymard.com/blog/people-think-registration-leads-to-spam

Comment: Having to register/signup for eCom sites can prove a pain point to customers, especially if it isn't spelt out what the trade off is for giving over personal information.  The site I am working on is not an eCom site. The article assumes that customer will receive a newsletter or spam. 

The site I am working on and it states it in my original query..
"The sign up/registration process asks for name, email, password. An email is sent on confirmation, there aren’t any follow up emails unless the customer explicitly requests it."